# Best way to implement an "Inheritance Square"

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here is my class diagram.

[image]

The problem is in `AgendaInstance` (see red dot). I'm trying to inherit (reuse) `Agenda.Tasks` to contain its own tasks, which are of type `TaskInstance`, a subtype of `Task`.

I can put `this.Tasks.Add(new TaskInstance());` inside `AgendaInstance`. That code works, but the problem comes in when I try to serialize or bind. Since `Tasks` is statically bound to `Task` all that gets serialized (e.g., to xml) or bound (e.g., to a grid row) are the properties of `Task`, not `TaskInstance`.

Is there a design pattern I can use here to overcome this issue? I don't want to shadow (new) `Tasks` in `AgendaInstance`. That would defeat the purpose of having an inheritance hierarchy. My midi-chlorians tell me there's a solution that is higher than directly dealing with serialization or binding specifics; it's a "deeper" issue that lends itself to a more fundamental solution. I'm going to fiddle around with generics but perhaps you know of an even better way or a better pattern.

Comment: Seems like you might want to be using a generic class such as `Agenda<T> where T : ITask` so that your `AgendaInstance` class is actually `AgendaInstance<TaskInstance>` so that `Tasks` returns a collection of `TaskInstance` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `Agenda` generic on the `Task`, like this:

```
class Agenda<T> where T : Task {
    public IList<T> Tasks {get; private set;}
    ...
}
class AgendaInstance<TaskInstance> {
    ...
}
```

Now there is only one `Task` property in the hierarchy. However, `Agenda` requires a type parameter to be instantiated, so what used to be a "plain" `Agenda` becomes `Agenda<Task>`.

Answer (score 1):

90% of my experience with xml serialization is bad. They tend to break inheritance model and does not support interfaces. Therefore, it resulting you to hack and tinker the existing class to suit the serialization. `XmlIgnore` and duplicated properties usually come to hand when dealing with it.

Therefore usually I create another class for the serialization purpose only. Ex: `AgendaSerializable`, with `TaskSerializeable` as Tasks. The benefit is: you keep your inheritance and data model clean, while you need to handle with data conversion as the cons.

may the force be with you.

Comment: Yeah the xml serialization really litters up the class. I've been reading up on AOP lately, in particular PostSharp because you can adorn your classes with attributes that indicate handlers (called "Aspects") of various cross-cutting concerns like logging, serialization, contracts. You are so correct to put it in a seperate class, and I'd like to write an `Aspect` that handles xml serialization. The aspect is a seperate class, and maybe I can write it generically so it can be used with any class! I'll let you know if I have any luck and thanks.